# Unity3D My Animation for Crouch walking is Jittering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't seem to get my animation for crouch walking to stop stuttering, like it is constantly being cut off and starting over again. attached is my code for animation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;

    private float slowV = 0.3f;
    private float fastV = 1f;

    private float blendSpeed = .6f;

    private float time;
    private float timeX;

    private float timeY;

    private bool crouch;
    private bool crouch2;

    void Start()
    {
        time = 0;
        timeX = 0;
        timeY = 0;
        crouch = false;
        crouch2 = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(crouch);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouchWalk", true);
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouch", false);

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouch", true);
        }
        else
        {
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouchWalk", false);
            player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouch", false);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    time = Mathf.Clamp(time + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, fastV);
                    player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (time < slowV)
                    {
                        time = Mathf.Clamp(time + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, slowV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time = Mathf.Clamp(time - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, slowV, fastV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    time = Mathf.Clamp(time - blendSpeed * 2 * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, fastV);
                    player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (time > -slowV)
                    {
                        time = Mathf.Clamp(time - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -slowV, fastV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time = Mathf.Clamp(time + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, -slowV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (time > 0f)
                {
                    time = Mathf.Clamp(time - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 1f);
                }
                else
                {
                    time = Mathf.Clamp(time + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -1f, 0f);
                }
                player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("y", time);
            }


            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX + blendSpeed * 2 * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, fastV);
                    player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (timeX < slowV)
                    {
                        timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, slowV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, slowV, fastV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX - blendSpeed * 2 * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, fastV);
                    player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (timeX > -slowV)
                    {
                        timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -slowV, fastV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -fastV, -slowV);
                        player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (timeX > 0f)
                {
                    timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX - blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 1f);
                }
                else
                {
                    timeX = Mathf.Clamp(timeX + blendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -1f, 0f);
                }

                player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("x", timeX);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("jump", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is a screen snip of my animator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Muu.png)

I have a short video capture of the problem in game but i'm not sure how to attach it here

I thought at first it was being interrupted by another animation, I tried to isolate it by assigning isolated keys and trying different node connections in the animator window

I tried separating it from all the other animations by putting it into if else statements

I've scoured the net for answers

I would appreciate any help or insight into this problem

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR, Make sure that your parameters are correct

I got it to work, I can't pinpoint exactly what was wrong with my first version but after implementing your code @Voidsay, looking at the animator while playing the scene this is what I discovered:

Firstly I tried to implement the code and animator exactly as you described, but it still didn't work. Then I started experimenting and changed my crouch and crouchwalk animation states into a single blendtree, which is also what I originally intended.

I noticed the animation bar for my crouchwalk state was going way too fast, and that lead to me noticing that the parameter controlling my crouchwalk blendtree was too low, leading to the crouchwalk to blend at a point that made it *look* like it was stuttering.(Exactly how it looked when I first had this problem)

I changed the code to properly reach the max blend value and now it works

It might have been a combination of both logic and parameter issues, or the former and then the latter but I guess I'll never know.

This was my first time working with the animator so I probably wasn't familiar enough with it.

Anyway, Thank you @Voidsay for the help, your creative liberty is also much better than my spaghetti if else's

This is my current code and anim controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Animator anim;

    [SerializeField] float slowV = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField] float fastV = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float blendSpeed = .6f;

    private float adjustedBlendSpeed;
    private Vector2 dir;



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("CrouchStart");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("CrouchEnd");
        }

        Vector2 dirTarget = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;

        anim.SetBool("Walking", dirTarget.magnitude > 0.1f);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            dirTarget *= fastV;
            adjustedBlendSpeed = blendSpeed * 2;
        }
        else
        {
            dirTarget *= slowV;
            adjustedBlendSpeed = blendSpeed;
        }
        Vector2 accel = (dirTarget - dir).normalized * adjustedBlendSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        dir += accel;
        anim.SetFloat("x", dir.x);
        anim.SetFloat("y", dir.y);

        anim.SetFloat("crouchX", dir.x);
        anim.SetFloat("crouchY", dir.y);
    }
}
```

[Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsaeJ.png)

Comment: make sure to mark your answer as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning from `Any State` also includes the state that you are transitioning to. You are using a bool to determine crouching. When you set that to true, the animation begins to transition from whatever state it was in, into the crouch animation. However next frame the bool is most likely still true. Once more you start jumping from `Any State` (which is now `Crouched Walk`) and begin transitioning to `Crouched Walk`. The result is as dumb as it sounds. You transition from the somewhere in the middle of your animation back to the beginning and the crouch walk seems to jitter.

To avoid issues with `Any State` transitions you should use a [Trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html).

```csharp
player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("CrouchStart");
```

In this case I've called it `CrouchStart` You'll have to create this new animator trigger variable and bind it to the transition from `Any State` to `Couched Walk`.

Your code is currently set up in a way that would cause the trigger to be reactivated every frame if you only do a simple swap. It would be a bit wordy to explain how to make it work with `GetButtonDown` and handle all the stuff around that, so I have taken the liberty of rewriting your code. Nested else if dependency hell is no fun, so I cleaned it up for you. It *should* still work exactly the same, but I didn't test it too much.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Animator anim;//you never use the player gameobject anyway

    [SerializeField] float slowV = 0.3f;//made Serialized, so you can adjust in the editor
    [SerializeField] float fastV = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float blendSpeed = .6f;

    private float adjustedBlendSpeed;
    private Vector2 dir;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("CrouchStart");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("CrouchEnd");
        }

        //axis Horizontal AD, Vertical WS by default
        Vector2 dirTarget = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;

        anim.SetBool("Walking", dirTarget.magnitude > 0.1f);

        //some creative liberty was taken to avoid else if condition hell
        //it *should* still function like before
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            dirTarget *= fastV;
            adjustedBlendSpeed = blendSpeed * 2;
        }
        else
        {
            dirTarget *= slowV;
            adjustedBlendSpeed = blendSpeed;
        }
        Vector2 accel = (dirTarget - dir).normalized * adjustedBlendSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        dir += accel;
        anim.SetFloat("x", dir.x);
        anim.SetFloat("y", dir.y);
    }
}
```

The animator is basically the same as before. I've added transitions between the `Crouch` and `Crouch Walk` state, so I wouldn't have to do it in code. I'm also only using a single crouch trigger for both `Crouch` and `Crouch Walk`. Ignore the odd names for the states and the warning, I just didn't bother making the animations.

[image: Reconstructed animator setup]

As you can see the transition from `Any State` to the `Crouch` and `Crouch Walk` gets the same `CrouchStart` trigger **and** the `Walking` bool. Both conditions have to be met for the transition to start. The transitions back to the blend tree use the `CrouchEnd` trigger.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it still displays the same behavior. I have tried just replacing (player.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("crouchWalk", true);) with setTrigger, I've tried adding ResetTrigger into my else statement, I have tried using getKeyDown instead of getkey with setTrigger, I've made sure that I've bound my trigger parameter to my transition. Maybe I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: @JC sorry my bad, I didn't look at your code before finalizing my answer. Nothing wrong with it, but you're using the "button hold" logic that backfires. The trigger probably works completely fine, but if it is being set every frame you end up with the exact same problem as before. I will add to my answer.

Comment: @JC I supplemented my answer. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. Just got it working and posted an answer explaining